# Put a comma before a specific word in .csv

Tags: debian, csv

I need a script for .csv file to put before a specific word, a comma. I have a text with about 100.000 lines.

Comment: We would appreciate seeing a sample from the file, and to know how you'd like to change it. Just "inserting a comma before a word in a file" is a bit broad.

Comment: 350 Gifford Street, New Westminster, BC V3M 1K1, Canada

Comment: So what I need is to put it after word street and before word Canada

Comment: Please update the text of the question with all relevant information. Feel free to anonymize any data.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -e 's/\<word\>/,word/g' file.csv
```

Your scenario

```
$ sed -e 's/\<Street\>/Street,/g' -e 's/\<Canada\>/, Canada/g'
```

Comment: If the affected column in the CSV file isn't quoted already, it needs to become quoted.

Comment: Let's say I have `a,b,c,"d,e,f",g`. That's five fields. Inserting a comma into the second field will require it to be quoted as `",b"`, otherwise you're inserting a field and shifting all the other field to the right. The question is painfully unclear as to what the OP's intention is, since "inserting a comma" is ambiguous in the context of CSV data. It could mean insert a comma as part of a field (in which case the field needs to be quoted), or insert an empty field.

Comment: @Kusalananda KK I got you, you're right. But as you said, the question is ambiguous, the csv could be separated by ";" so why not pointing that out instead of downvoteing?